# Regarding Authlogic and page redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rest, routes, authlogic

I am using authlogic for authentication in my Rails app. Have named routes for the frequent actions, viz:

> map.login "login", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "new"
>
> map.logout "logout", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "destroy"
>
> map.register "register", :controller => "users", :action => "new"
>
> map.edit 'user/edit/:id', :controller => "users", :action => "edit"

But also in my routes.rb i have these automatically created REST routes too:

> map.resources :user_sessions
>
> map.resources :users

The problem now is that a user can login from two different routes. Ex:
From,
 http://localhost/login and also from http ://localhost/user_sessions/new.
How do i restrict access only from the named route i have defined and not allow from user_sessions/new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude `new` action from your restful routes. Very simple:

```
map.resources :user_sessions, :except => [:new]
```

See the marvellous [ApiDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Resources/resources) for reference.